# Using RPC calls to run query on many2many in javascript Odoo-8

Tags: javascript, mysql, odoo, rpc

Hello I'm trying to fetch results of query in JavaScript using RPC calls in odoo8. But the problem here is that I need to fetch from many2many field as well and I don't have much idea of its syntax. 
I'm using query() function for fetching result from a simple field and is working fine.

```
 var rec = new openerp.Model('my.model');
 rec.query(['name']['value'])
    .filter(['id','=',2])
    .limit(1)
    .all().then(function (pro)
    {
    alert(pro[0]['name'])
    });
```

1)How this technique will be used with many2many field?
2)Secondly I'm using the model name to fetch here but when using many2many, a relational table is created whose model name is not known.How to resolve this?